# C Struct problem

Tags: c

I've been searching for some answer to this problem but can't figure it out.

I have a structure:

```
typedef struct  {
    BYTE  hour;      
    BYTE  minute;    
    BYTE  second;   
    BYTE  dom;     
    BYTE month;
    BYTE year;      
} t_time_date ;
```

And a serial port receive function:

```
g_curr_td.year = g_rx_buffer[3];
g_curr_td.month = g_rx_buffer[4];
g_curr_td.dom = g_rx_buffer[5];
g_curr_td.hour = g_rx_buffer[6];
g_curr_td.minute = g_rx_buffer[7];
g_curr_td.second = g_rx_buffer[8];
```

I have verified the `g_rx_buffer` is correct and contains data.  If I hard code a number in to the variable it works:

```
g_curr_td.year = 10;  /* this works */
```

However, running live data it crashes and seems to be writing data somewhere else in memory.  Can anyone see something wrong in my setup?

Thanks.

Comment: You should post the byte array coming over the wire so we can better help you

Comment: We need to see more code. The problem is probably not with your struct. How is g_curr_td defined, for instance? What happens if you assign the various rx_buffer elements to local variables rather than your struct?

Comment: Also the actual error would help.

Comment: t_time_date g_current; /* is how the struct is defined */

Comment: g_rx_buffer (in code) is the same as rx_buffer.  I just left off the g_ as I was typing.  There is only one variable.

Comment: There is no error code.  My microprocessor resets or locks up which led me to believe there was a pointer problem.

Comment: Paul, the various rx_buffer elements are working.  I have 40 or 50 different command functions.  They all work fine except this one.  It is the only one using the struct.

Comment: pmg, yes.  i changed for the post so it would be easier to read but missed it in my remark.

Comment: How are `g_rx_buffer` and `BYTE` defined?  What compiler are you using?

Comment: bta, g_rx_buffer is a byte array and byte is defined as a char.  This is an 8 bit micro and I'm using IAR compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For debugging purposes, you can try creating a function that takes arguments for all the struct members, something like:

```
/* Assumes g_curr_td is a global variable. */
void FillStruct( BYTE hour, BYTE minute, BYTE second, BYTE dom, BYTE month, BYTE year )
{ 
    g_curr_td.year = year;
    g_curr_td.month = month;
    g_curr_td.dom = dom;
    g_curr_td.hour = hour;
    g_curr_td.minute = minute;
    g_curr_td.second = second;
}
```

Using a function like this should make the assembly code the same whether you're using values from the buffer or constant expressions.  If it still crashes, it's probably something with your buffer, even though you do seem to have checked all the angles I could think of dealing with the buffer.

You can call this function as `FillStruct( g_rx_buffer[3], g_rx_buffer[4], g_rx_buffer[5], g_rx_buffer[6], g_rx_buffer[7], g_rx_buffer[8] )`, and if that crashes, call it as `FillStruct( a, b, c, d, e, f )`, where a, b, c, d, e, and f are either the original arguments or new constant arguments.  Try replacing the arguments one at a time and see if it's just one particular field that's failing, or if it's any field that fails.

EDIT:  Also, exactly what is your `typedef` or `#define` for the `BYTE` type, what compiler and OS are you using, and are you using any pragmas, e.g. to pack the structure to byte alignment?

Comment: +1 for the note about the alignment.  If you are dealing with fixed-length data that is coming in from another device, I would recommend using standard fixed-width data types like `uint8_t` (from stdint.h) and packing your structures for one-byte alignment.

Comment: sskuce, I tried this and it worked!  Thanks for your suggestion.  I don't understand why though.  Do you have any idea?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd go with a compiler bug, but I can't say for sure without knowing what compiler you're using, what version, what architecture, etc.  If I were you, I'd try to write the simplest possible  program that duplicates the problem without using the serial port, e.g. something that reads values from the keyboard and then tries to fill the struct with those values, then send that program to the compiler vendor (or community, if it's gcc or something else like that) to see what's up.

Comment: It's IAR embedded compiler for 8 bit.  I was sure it wasn't the serial aspect but couldn't figure it out.  It was a big help to get a fresh idea to troubleshoot.  Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not familiar with IAR's products or reputation.  I would definitely try and make a simple program that reproduces the problem and give it to them to test with.  Are you using their latest version?  If not, it appears they offer free 30-day evaluations of the full version or completely free code size-limited versions.

Answer (score 1):

Does g_rx_buffer have at least 9 BYTEs of data?

Answer (score 1):

Although I may not answer your question directly, this may help you have cleaner code:

Have a struct for the incoming data format:

```
typedef struct  {
    BYTE  year;      
    BYTE  month;    
    BYTE  dom;   
    BYTE  hour;     
    BYTE  minute;
    BYTE  second;      
} t_time_input_date __attribute__((packed));


// First you can make sure the data is received in its whole
assert(g_rx_length >= sizeof(t_time_input_date) + 3);

t_time_input_date *in_date = (t_time_input_date *)(g_rx_buffer+3);

g_curr_td.year = in_date->year;
g_curr_td.month = in_date->month;
g_curr_td.dom = in_date->dom;
g_curr_td.hour = in_date->hour;
g_curr_td.minute = in_date->minute;
g_curr_td.second = in_date->second;
```

This way your code will be cleaner, and it will help you in 3 months.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it wouldn't compile. 
t_time_date *td_ptr; td_ptr = (t_time_date *)(&g_uart_rx_buffer + 3); g_current.year = td_ptr->year;

Comment: That's because you typed something totally different from what I've suggested

Comment: No, sorry I was having trouble formatting that message.  What I left out was I changed it to the above and it compiles now.  It probably has the completely wrong meaning now.  I do appreciate your comments though.

Comment: @Stephen- You added an `&` that wasn't in Nicolas' sample code.  That's likely the source of your error.

Comment: @sskuce, you are right, I've corrected the problem (that would be the syntax with GCC).

Comment: If all the elements are the same, it shouldn't need to be packed. (And if they're called `BYTE` I sure hope they don't need any padding, or else the people who designed your system had some interesting ideas about `BYTE`s.)

Comment: @Chris, I tried, and you are right. But in the general case, you want to say 'pack that thing' to map some raw bytes of memory to a struct: the day you use a 16bits variable, or a 32bits one, you won't need hours of debugging.

Comment: So, Stephen, you tried Nick's code.  Do you still get the same result of crashing when you assign a variable, but not a constant?  Make sure you incorporate the correct 'packing' syntax for your compiler in the struct definition.

Comment: I tried again using Nick's syntax and it still resets.  This is an 8 bit micro so I don't have some of the attributes you are referring to like 'packed' and 'assert'.

Comment: If it's a compiler for an 8-bit micro, you may not need the packing attribute, as I'll be everything is byte-aligned anyway.  I would definitely be asking the compiler vendor if this is a possible bug.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have any system so sincronize data over the serial? How do you guarantee that g_rx_buffer[3] is really g_curr_td.year?

Answer (score 0):

The only error source I can see here is the access on the g_rx_buffer. Is the array from g_rx_buffer big enough?

Maybe you can loop over the g_rx_buffer and show us the content of this array.

Comment: Yes, the buffer size is larger than the command string received.  I don't have a good way to capture the string as it is in hex.  It looks like this 01 0A F2 0A 0B 03 13 2D 1E ## where ## = checksum, 0A = size, F2 = command, the rest is 11-03-10 @ 1:45:30.

Answer (score 0):

What is g_rx_buffer ? If it is not an array of BYTE and not a pointer to BYTE, `g_rx_buffer[3]` is not the same as `((BYTE*)g_rx_buffer)[3]`.

Comment: BYTE g_rx_buffer[RX_BUFFER_SIZE]; /* where buff size is 25 */